# Event listener only makes loop loop once

Tags: javascript, loops, dom-events

E: Was not aware that assigning the number property to an input box would still pas it on as a String thank you for the replies!.

My eventlistener makes it so that it only loops through my for loop one time then stops.

Now I am sure the solution is simple as what but I cannot seem to find the problem.

It works fine if you just run the function and input the values by hand.

```js
startButton.addEventListener("click",function(){
           floorFizz = document.getElementById("floor").value;
           capFizz = document.getElementById("cap").value;
           incrementFizz = document.getElementById("increment").value;
           FizzBuzz(floorFizz,capFizz,incrementFizz);
       });

function FizzBuzz(floor,cap,increment){
    for(let i=floor; i<cap; i+= increment){
        console.log("iteration")
        if(i%3 === 0 && i%5 === 0){
            console.log(i + "=FizzBuzz")
        }
        else if(i%3 === 0){
            console.log(i + "=Fizz")
        }
        else if(i%5 === 0){
            console.log(i + "=Buzz")
        }
        else{
            console.log(i)
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<button id="startButton">Start</button>
<div id=floor>1</div>
<div id=cap>100</div>
<div id=increment>1</div>
```

No error message just only goes through the loop once.

```
let floorVal = document.createElement('input');
        floorVal.setAttribute('type','number');
        floorVal.id = "floor";
        floorVal.setAttribute('placeholder','Starting number')
        parent.appendChild(floorVal);
```

Comment: What are the values for floor and cap and increment?

Comment: floor 1 cap 100 increment 1

Comment: ```let floorVal = document.createElement('input');
        floorVal.setAttribute('type','number');
        floorVal.id = "floor";
        floorVal.setAttribute('placeholder','Starting number')
        parent.appendChild(floorVal);```

Comment: `console.log(typeof floorFizz, typeof capFizz, typeof incrementFizz)`

Comment: I converted this to a code snippet for you. I am sure this will be to do with how you handle the numbers. Are you passing in integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

convert the values to numbers...

```
floorFizz = Number(document.getElementById("floor").value);
capFizz = Number(document.getElementById("cap").value);
incrementFizz = Number(document.getElementById("increment").value);
```

Comment: This worked, i'm not sure why tho as i declare the input type as number.

Comment: Does not matter, value is still a string.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work fine once you use `parseInt` to make sure you are getting numbers and not strings:

```js
document.getElementById('startButton').addEventListener("click",function(){
           floorFizz = parseInt(document.getElementById("floor").value);
           capFizz = parseInt(document.getElementById("cap").value);
           incrementFizz = parseInt(document.getElementById("increment").value);
           FizzBuzz(floorFizz,capFizz,incrementFizz);
       });
function FizzBuzz(floor,cap,increment){
    for(let i=floor; i<cap; i+= increment){
        console.log("ittaration")
        if(i%3 === 0 && i%5 === 0){
            console.log(i + "=FizzBuzz")
        }
        else if(i%3 === 0){
            console.log(i + "=Fizz")
        }
        else if(i%5 === 0){
            console.log(i + "=Buzz")
        }
        else{
            console.log(i)
        }
    }
}
```

```html
Floor: <input type="number" id="floor" value="0" /><br/>
Cap: <input type="number" id="cap" value="100" /><br/>
Inc: <input type="number" id="increment" value="1"/><br/>

<button id="startButton">Start</button>
```